# Prevent a JS script from execution from another script

Tags: javascript

I have two JS scripts, S1 and S2, executing in this order. Both are known but S1 can absolutely not be modified, moved or removed (third party masterpage). Dev have full control on S2 however (custom made).

I would like to prevent S1 from executing, but i can only modify S2 (which is after S1) or create new S3 script between S1 and S2.

Is that possible ?

I'm not sure i'm explaining it clearly :(

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly not.

You can't prevent something from happening after it has already happened.

It might be possible to undo the work of the first script (e.g. by removing event handlers).

Comment: S1 script is known but calls something in blackbox logic, no idea how it works there and therefore can't undo it.